# How to provide offline access to an app in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, offline-mode

I am new to React Native and currently building an App in Expo. I am trying to add an offline feature in my app. Take Profile Screen for e.g. if a user updates his/ her name in the app and it doesn't have the internet access/ is offline so when the user gets back online his/ her name will be uploaded on the database. Till then, it should be able to see his updated name on his phone only.

So far I have build only front end part which accepts Name only. But don't know how to add this feature in my app ?

I am good at developing frontend but don't have a good knowledge how to connect frontend to db and backend. It will be helpful if someone can put some highlight for that?

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this type of offline feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to achieve something like this. This works [out of the box](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) with [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), which is one way to accomplish offline functionality/persistence.

Check out this: [Using Firebase with Expo](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/).

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have never used Cloud Firestore though. So using Cloud Firestore, I can still access the data on the front-end and my data will be stored while offline and when there is an internet access, my whole data will be updated. Right ?? Is there any other way also to achieve this. Cause I don't want to depend on one solution. It will be better if I will have plenty of options to choose ? Thanks again, for this options

Comment: The information @Riwen provided is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, you can access the data, and it will be uploaded when connection is (re-)established. For solutions not involving Firebase, see @Padmini’s answer. You’ll have to do the heavy-lifting yourself.

Comment: But Firebase is considered the worst, I mean it is good for practise but not for production apps. Also I can't use AsyncStorage because at some the data gonna be large. I want something which will be good for production apps and able to sync online and offline data. Do you think, it is possible ?

Comment: Considered the worst *by whom*? Anyway, you can always use the file system for storing data.

Answer (score 1):

One more way is you can use Asyncstorage if it's only a name field you want to store offline [expo asyncstorage](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/).

To send the updated name to database when user is online, you can use Netinfo [expo netinfo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/netinfo/) to check whether user is able to access internet or not.

Comment: Yeah, it may work but what if I have plenty of data. Storage system may be become a mess in those time. The name field is just one small which I took as an example though. In future, I will have plenty of data. So I need a better option for that.

Comment: Can it really be used for large data though. Like for for example creating a ticketing tool app may be

Comment: No it's not recommended as I have mentioned above it's useful for storing small data , for example I used it for storing jwt token (in my App requirement was token will expire in 2 months)  as Redux will loose state if device is restarted or app is closed due to some reason. If you need to store large data offline then like @Riwen suggested Cloud Firestore is recommended.

Comment: Ok Ok, got it. Thanks

Comment: But Firebase is considered the worst, I mean it is good for practise but not for production apps. Also I can't use AsyncStorage because at some the data gonna be large. I want something which will be good for production apps and able to sync online and offline data. Do you think, it is possible ?